# Menu items don't respond in CollapsingTollbarLayout (AppBarLayout)

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-touch-event

I have an Activity with collapsing Toolbar and everything works fine except touch events with menu items and back arrow button.

If Toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) puts outside CollapsingTollbarLayout everything works well.

As i understand, collapsing is grabbing touch event from the toolbar and it can't be reached, right?
I'm tried requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent set to false, but no luck.

Like this:

```
mToolbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Please help me understand what did i miss. Thanks a lot!

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/sub_goals_list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/sub_goals_collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:titleEnabled="true"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/sub_goals_list_toolbar"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TitleSubGoalsStyle"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="115dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:elevation="3dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bg_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_create_big_goal"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@id/sub_goals_list_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/sub_goals_list_container"
                android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                style="@style/DetailsOfTheBigGoal"
                >

                // Some TextView here

            </RelativeLayout>

            <com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.NumberProgressBar
                app:progress_reached_color="@color/darkBlueSea"
                app:progress_unreached_color="@color/brightBlue"
                app:progress_text_color="@color/darkBlueSea"
                app:progress_text_size="14sp"
                app:progress_unreached_bar_height="3dp"
                app:progress_reached_bar_height="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/big_goal_inner_progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="94dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_sub_goal_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_fab"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/sub_goals_list_container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My menu code looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        case R.id.delete_big_goal:
            try {
                IntentionDAOHelper.deleteIntention(mBigGoal, mBigGoalsDAO);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try adding android:clipchildren="false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by adding another one Toolbar here:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_sub_goal_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_fab"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/sub_goals_list_container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/sub_goals_list_toolbar_uncollapse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I bet it's not the best way (far far away from it) to do it, but it works fine.